# Merge flat list into hierarchy using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
// simple EF projection (anonymous type returned)
var superHerosData = from hero in filteredHeros 
                     select new
                     {
                        hero.HeroId,
                        hero.FirstName
                        hero.LastName
                        Powers = from power in hero.Powers
                                 select new
                                 {
                                    power.PowerId;
                                 }
                    };

List<SuperHeroModel> superHeros = new List<SuperHeroModel>();

// populates superHeros (collection of SuperHeroModel) with the values in superHerosData
MapToModel(superHerosData, ref superHeros)

IQueryable<DAL.Models.Power> powersData = from hero in filteredHeros
                                          from power in hero.Powers
                                          select power;
```

Getting powers is expensive and has better performance if done in a single operation (flat collection)

```
List<PowerModel> powers = await GetPowers(powersData);
```

I need to replace the Powers collection inside each SuperHeroModel (of the superHeros collection) with a collection of the matching models from the powers collection.

What's a good LINQ-to-objects way to inject the flat list of powers into the hierarchy of superHeros?
`SuperHeroModel.Powers` currently contains a collection of `PowerModel` with just the PowerId populated

**Update:**

Something like this might work, but it doesn't feel very Linq friendly. I was hoping for a more elegant solution:

```
foreach (SuperHeroModel superHero in superHeros)
{
    IEnumerable<int> superHeroPowerIds = superHero.Powers.Select(p => p.PowerId);
    List<PowerModel> superHeroPowers = powers.Where(power => superHeroPowerIds.Contains(power.PowerId)).ToList();

    superHero.Powers = superHeroPowers;
}
```

Comment: What do you have after `MapToModel`? As I understand your `SuperHeroModel` should have some property called `Powers` holding collection of actual `Power` objects not just `PowerIds`?

Comment: SuperHeroModel does have a property called Powers of type List<PowerModel>. I limit the query to only contain the Id's so there would be a unique key I could use to join the flat list of powers on. As I said, the work in GetPowers is expensive, and works better if done as a flat list, so I don't pull all the data in the first query.

Comment: @mbursill: I don't understand, won't you have to get the powers at least once anyway? What, specifically, is precluding the `from hero in filteredHeros from powerId in hero.Powers join power in Powers on powerId equals power.Id ...`

Comment: Less `var` plz!  Many of the types above are known.

Comment: @Andrew The call to GetPowers does more than just an EF query. Without going outside the scope of the question, it's safe to say GetPowers is necessary. While I could include more in my projection of the Powers POCO, it seems unnecessary since ultimately it would be replaced by the returned types of the GetPowers call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach (SuperHeroModel superHero in superHeros)
{
    IEnumerable<int> powerIds = superHero.Powers.Select(p => p.PowerId);
    superHeros.Powers = powers.Where(p => powerIds.Contains(p.PowerId));
}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault will return only one PowerModel from the powers collection. It would fail because superHero.Powers is a collection and needs to therefore be assigned to another collection. I keep the PowerId in each PowerModel of superHeros.Powers so I have a key I can later use to join the results of GetPowers on.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and misread part of the question. I updated the answer.

Comment: This is what I already came up with (see update in question). Thought there might be a more linq-friendly way, but I suppose it's about as good as it gets.